# Ruby on Rails: How to strip insignificant zeros on dynamically added items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, formatting

I have an **Invoice** to which **Items** can be added using some jQuery magic.

Controller:

```
def new    
  @invoice = Invoice.new
  @invoice.with_blank_items(current_user) 
  @title = "New invoice"
end
```

Model:

```
def with_blank_items(user, n = 1)
  n.times do
    items.build(:price => user.preference.hourly_rate)
  end
  self
end
```

View:

```
<%= f.text_field number_with_precision(:price, :strip_insignificant_zeros => true) %>
```

Now the problem is that the price of a newly added item is always displayed in the format **XX.X**, i.e. with one decimal place, no matter if it is zero or not.

I don't like that and I want a price of 50 to be displayed as *50* and not as *50.0*.

Once the invoice gets saved to the database, unnecessary zeros get dropped and that's perfect.

How can I strip insignificant zeros on newly added items as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to format the values the right way before assigning:

```
items.build(:price => '%g' % user.preference.hourly_rate)
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks! But I don't understand what the code actually does, especially the %g bit...

Comment: It works like sprintf in C: [http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25)

Comment: Ok, I just realise your solution works when a new invoice view is rendered, but not when items are added with jQuery.

Comment: So you create items using jQuery directly on your page?

Comment: Yes, the first item will be included by default when a new invoice is initiated. Your code works well on that one. When further items are added (through jQuery), the formatting is still wrong though. The price is displayed as e.g. *70.0* where it should be *70*.

Comment: Be careful! It looks like it works but if you pass
21385524.0031
You'll get:
2.13855e+07

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I believe your issue can fixed with a JavaScript function (which removed the decimal places).

Try something like:

```
function removeDecimal(val){
    return val.toFixed(0);
}
```

These are my test cases:

```
removeDecimal(123.45) -> 123
removeDecimal(123.4)  -> 123
removeDecimal(123)    -> 123
```